# C# - Iterating through repeated context menu items with foreach loops

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, foreach, contextmenu, repeat

I'm currently working on a small project which requires some repetition in some context menu items. The menu starts with a right click context menu and branches out with different colours, and then to objects. Depending on the colour and object selected, the object on the form will change. It's pretty messy, but unfortunately I can't see an easier way of getting this done (and thankfully it only needs to be done for the one menu).

I've created the colours as menu items and added them, but each colour repeats the same 8 objects as such:

```
foreach (MenuItem i in colors.MenuItems)
{
    MenuItem one = new MenuItem();
    one.Text = "One";
    MenuItem two = new MenuItem();
    two.Text = "Two";
    MenuItem three = new MenuItem();
    three.Text = "Three";
    MenuItem four = new MenuItem();
    four.Text = "Four";
    MenuItem five = new MenuItem();
    five.Text = "Five";
    MenuItem six = new MenuItem();
    six.Text = "Six";
    MenuItem seven = new MenuItem();
    seven.Text = "Seven";
    MenuItem eight = new MenuItem();
    eight.Text = "Eight";
    i.MenuItems.Add(one);
    i.MenuItems.Add(two);
    i.MenuItems.Add(three);
    i.MenuItems.Add(four);
    i.MenuItems.Add(five);
    i.MenuItems.Add(six);
    i.MenuItems.Add(seven);
    i.MenuItems.Add(eight);
}
```

First things first, I figured it's inefficient to have all the object menu items being created inside the foreach loop, so I moved them just before it. When I did this, the objects were only added to the final colour, instead of all of them. This seemed rather strange and I'd appreciate it if someone could explain why this occurrs.

Secondly, the plan is to change the object that's been right clicked based on which menu selection the person selects. Is there an easier way to get the menu item selected other than having a Menu.Click event for each individual menu item?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Bob

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First things first, I figured it's inefficient to have all the object
>   menu items being created inside the foreach loop, so I moved them just
>   before it. When I did this, the objects were only added to the final
>   colour, instead of all of them. This seemed rather strange and I'd
>   appreciate it if someone could explain why this occurrs.

Each `MenuItem` can only be a child of one object. The framework is silently making it a child of the last thing it is assigned to be the child of.

Much repetition can be removed from your code by taking an approach similar to the one in Alex Siepman's solution. I've added a `Click` handler and made other small changes.

```
void Something()
{
    MyColoredObject o = //something
    var textValues = new[] {"Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight"};

    foreach (MenuItem color in colors.MenuItems)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
        {
            MenuItem newItem = new MenuItem();
            newItem.Text = textValues[i];
            newItem.Click += NumberClickHandler(o, color, i);
            color.MenuItems.Add(newItem);
        }
    }
}
EventHandler NumberClickHandler(MyColoredObject o, MenuItem color, int num)
{
    return (s, e) =>
    {
        // assign the color to o as identified by color and num
    };
}
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you so much. I unfortunately can not upvote your answer as stackoverflow requires me to have 15 reputation before I can do so. I'll be sure to come back when I have 15+ reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I can not answer al your questions because the context is not clear to me, but at least the code can be shorter:

```
var textvalues = new[] {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight"};

foreach (MenuItem i in colors)
{
    var newItems = textvalues.Select(t => new MenuItem{Text = t});
    foreach (MenuItem newItem in newItems)
    {
        i.MenuItems.Add(newItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to reply. I unfortunately can not upvote your answer as stackoverflow requires me to have 15 reputation before I can do so. I'll be sure to come back when I have 15+ reputation.